# Is it possible to access video data on both cameras on ipad2 at the same time?

Tags: camera, video-streaming, video-capture, ipad-2

Could we get two live video streams at the same time? Or should I switch cameras to get two streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple, accessing both cameras at once is not supported. If you have access to the Apple Developer Forums, see [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/375558#375558).

Also, BTW, switching streams is quite slow in my experience and would be no substitute for accessing both cameras at once.